# Syntax error with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax

I recently wrote a stored procedure with those parameters:

```
@dFromDT DATE,
@dToDT DATE,
@sErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX),
@sPartCustom INT,
@sPartCustomFilter NVARCHAR(254),
@nIncludeMessage INT
```

I am trying to call the procedure with the line:

```
EXEC _MG_ERPPartFilter(CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01T00:00:00', 126), CONVERT(datetime, '2050-12-31T00:00:00', 126), '',5, '556', 0)
```

And I always get that error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Even when I write this line:

```
EXEC _MG_ERPPartFilter('2013-01-01','2050-12-31', '',5, '556', 0)
```

I get that error:

> Incorrect syntax near '2013-01-01'.

All the names are correct.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You cannot have expressions in the `EXEC` command - you need to have only literal values or SQL Server variables. Use a SQL Server variable to hold the result of the `CONVERT` and then use that variable in your `EXEC` call ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use parenthesis in your second example:

```
EXEC _MG_ERPPartFilter '2013-01-01','2050-12-31', '',5, '556', 0
```

and in first you have to convert values into temporary variables and pass them to `exec` command:

```
declare @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime

set @date1 = CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01T00:00:00', 126)
set @date2 = CONVERT(datetime, '2050-12-31T00:00:00', 126)

EXEC _MG_ERPPartFilter @date1, @date2, '',5, '556', 0
```